# Logging custom exceptions Python

Tags: python

I have a simple try and except statement. However I want to use logger exception to log the exception. What is the best way of only have 1 line of code for the logger.exception. In the exception base class ?

```
try:
    do_something()
except CustomBaseExecption, exc:
    logger.exception("Exception Raised:")
    raise GeneralError(exc)
except Exception as exc:
    logger.exception("Exception Raised:")
    raise GeneralError("Unknown Error")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing that's changed between two code blocks is GeneralError argument. Let's put a conditional there.

```
try:
    do_something()
except Exception as exc:
    logger.exception("Exception Raised:")
    raise GeneralError(exc if isinstance(exc, CustomBaseExecption) else "Unknown Error")
```